# Javascript Input value returns undefined (To do list program)

Tags: javascript, html-lists

For  the past day ive been banging my head to the wall i just cant get this to work
every time i try to create a to do list it returns undefined and i cant seem to detect what went wrong with the code
Im still in the learning process so please go easy

```js
function addToList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("candidate").Value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  li.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("toDoList").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="userToDoList">
        <input id="candidate" class="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New List..." />
        <button onclick="addToList()">Add</button>
      </div>
      <div class="addedLists">
        <ul id="toDoList"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
<script src="JS/Script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must have been frustrating. You used a capital V for `value`.

`.Value` is an invalid property. You're looking for `.value`

```js
function addToList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("candidate").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  li.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("toDoList").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="userToDoList">
        <input id="candidate" class="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New List..." />
        <button onclick="addToList()">Add</button>
      </div>
      <div class="addedLists">
        <ul id="toDoList"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
<script src="JS/Script.js"></script>

</html>
```